# How to convert ZÃƒÂ¤une to Zäune in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I receive a text string from a third party api with garbled character encodings.
When I print that string to the command line, the string contains words like

- ZÃƒÂ¤une instead of Zäune
- GartenmÃƒÂ¶bel instead of Gartenmöbel

etc.

What can I do, to fix the incoming text string with python 2.7, so it prints properly to the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
In [36]: print('ZÃƒÂ¤une'.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1'))
Zäune

In [37]: print('GartenmÃƒÂ¶bel'.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1'))
Gartenmöbel
```

---

I found this chain of encodings [guess_chain_encodings.py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082441/190597) which performs a brute-force search:

```
In [51]: 'ZÃƒÂ¤une'
Out[51]: 'Z\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa4une'

In [52]: 'Zäune'
Out[52]: 'Z\xc3\xa4une'
```

Running

```
guess_chain_encodings.py "'Z\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa4une'" "'Z\xc3\xa4une'"
```

yielded

```
'Z\xc3\x83\xc6\x92\xc3\x82\xc2\xa4une'.decode('utf_8').encode('cp1254').decode('utf_8_sig').encode('palmos')
```

A little playing around suggested that `cp1254` could be replaced by the (more common?) `cp1252`, and `utf_8_sig` could be replaced by `utf-8`, and the odd `palmos` could be replaced by `latin-1`.

Comment: Could you add some explanation for this decode/encode chain, please?

Comment: @WojciechWalczak: `cp1252` is a common encoding used by Windows. `utf-8` is a common encoding used on Unix. So part of the problem appears to be due to a Windows computer outputting a `cp1252` encoded string and a Unix computer interpreting that string as a `utf-8` encoded string, or vice versa. Meanwhile, `latin-1` is an encoding which converts unicode code points to their literal byte values. This suggests that compounding the problem is some machine which is receiving code points and interpreting them as bytes or vice versa.

Comment: Hi, the string with the garbled characters is of type "unicode". When I do print garbledString.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1'), I get UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u200e' in position 10739: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: `unicode` is always *encoded*, and `bytes` are always decoded. So if you have `unicode`, then skip the first `.decode()` and instead try: `garbledString.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1'`). This will leave you with a `utf-8` encoded string. If you are on Windows, you will want to decode this to obtain the desired `unicode`: `garbledString.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: did it.. this gives: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u200e' in position 16351: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Please post: `print(repr(garbledString))`.

Comment: You might also want to try: `garbledString.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Also note that the string you are receiving from the 3rd-party API is bytes, not unicode. So to address this problem at the source, we should be dealing with *that* string, not the unicode `garbledString`.

Answer (score 1):

The strings seem to be UTF-8 encoded twice.

Answer (score 0):

Notice also the console encoding - sometimes you can see your printed strings fine in the app, but it could fail to print in the console. [Here's very good guide](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) about Unicode in Python and its using techniques.