# Unicode string to Unicode character, Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I'm programming using Python 3.x. Say I have the following Unicode string:

`my_string =' \xed\x95\x9c'`

`'\xed\x95\x9c'` is actually the UTF-8 byte stream for the Korean character `한`. What's the easiest way to convert `my_string` to `한`? `my_string.decode('utf-8')` doesn't work because `my_string` is a Unicode string, not a byte string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible `encode`/`decode` chains which lead to the desired result. Here is one:

```
In [257]: '\xed\x95\x9c'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
Out[257]: '한'
```

[Here is the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082441/190597) I used to find this encode/decode chain.